ASP.NET Core with React.js application displaying blank page after deployment
I have deployed Asp.net Core with React.js application to IIS. The app is loading if I publish the code in Default Web Site. I have other app running on port 80 so, I have added separate application under Default Web Site but the app is displaying blank page. I verified from network tab that there is not issue in js and css loading.
Assume my app name is ExampleApp and it I have folder ExampleApp inside inetpub/wwwroot.
Example:

Code published under inetpub/wwwroot =>. http://localhost   => working
Code published under inetpub/wwwroot/ExampleApp. =>. http://localhost/ExampleApp - blank page

Thanks in advance!

I have installed .net core web hosting bundle package.
I have installed url rewrite. Not configured anything in iis.


please provide enough details such as logs or  minimal code to reproduce

Step 1: Create "React and Asp.net core" application. (I am using .net core 6.0)
Step 2 : Publish the application in iis "Default Web Site".

Find the index.html and vite.config.js files.
Then add <base href="/ExampleApp/" /> in index.html. Like below:

Add base: '/ExampleApp/', in vite.config.js file.

Then deploy the ReactApp1.Server project again, and host it under ExampleApp folder.



The above answer helped me to find the root cause but It did not really solved my problem. I am exploring the way to fix the issue. I will post the answer once fixed. Thank you so much for the help!!!

Below are the steps fixed my issue:
Installed .net core web hosting bundle 6.0 (for .net core 6.0).
Added "homepage":"/ExampleApp" in package.json file.
Replaced BrowserRoute to HashRouter.
